# Why is blender's API documentation so incomplete

Tags: python, scripting, documentation

I'm new to blender. I want to write some python script using Python API. But I found API in the official website is so incomplete(for example [bpy.data](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.data.html), it has only ONE page). Later, I found I can use CTRL+SPACE in the blender python console to find some methods and attributes, but I still feel inconvenient.

Did I do something wrong? Where can I found all of the APIs, or what is the correct workflow to write python script in blender?

Comment: What exactly is missing, can you give an example? The documentation is a community effort, just like the software development. If you find something that's missing get in contact with the developers and help us add it.

Comment: ^ This. Just ask a *real question* and we can help for sure.